# My SqlCommand query of inserting data values from textbox did not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
        public partial class Form4 : Form
        {
            String connectionString;
            SqlConnection connection;

            public Form4()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;   
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                addStudent();         
            }

            void addStudent()
            {
                using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                using (SqlCommand first = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    string idNum = textBox1.Text;
                    string lname = textBox2.Text;
                    string fname = textBox3.Text;
                    string course = comboBox1.Text;
```

The query for inserting values from textbox didn't work

```
                    first.CommandText="INSERT INTO Students (idNo, fName, lName, course) VALUES (@idNum, @fname, @lname, @course)";            
                    first.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idNum", idNum);
                    first.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname);
                    first.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname);
                    first.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", course);

                    try
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        first.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (SqlException e)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString(), "Error Message");
                    }
```

There is no error when I click the button, but if I click it again, I get an error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint.... Cannot add duplicate key value

but there is no new value in my database

```
                } 
            }      
        }
}
```

Comment: `first.CommandText="INSERT INTO Students (idNo, fName, lName, course, gender) VALUES (@idNum, @fname, @lname, @course)";` => are you sure this statement works by putting 4 values instead of 5? Check if `idNum` contains duplicate value from DB preventing insertion.

Comment: don't you want to insert gender to the database?

Comment: i have removed the gender value and parameter. but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement is incorrect. You have 5 parameters and passed only 4 values for them.

```
first.CommandText="INSERT INTO Students (idNo, fName, lName, course) VALUES (@idNum, @fname, @lname, @course)";            
first.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idNum", idNum);
first.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname);
first.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname);
first.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", course);
```

And idNum may be your primary key and set to auto increment in that case you don't require to pass idNo and if not auto incremented you should make sure you don't pass same idNo another time during insertion.

Comment: Or if `IdNo` in the database table is the primary key, but *not* an identity, then trying to add a second row with the same value **of course** is going to fail .....

Comment: my idNo is a primary key but I didn't set it as an auto increment.

Comment: @KarinaPadayhag Check what value is being passed to idNum and check whether that value already exists in db.

Comment: the table in my database is empty, that is why i'm confused why it has a duplicate key error..

Answer (score 0):

So, I have figured out that this code actually works but i didn't know because i thought that the table in my database would be updated but it would not, it was only the table in my dataset which was updated. Which means my code actually works in my dataset.